# Generating classes for Android to use with REST service & WCF2ANDROID - JSON serialization

Tags: android, wcf, rest

I'm writing an Android app that consumes a WCF RESTful service - I have a lot classes in the WCF app generated from existing DB using LINQ classes. In Android for simplifying REST usage I decided to use SpringSource with the REST Template. But a problem occurs when I want to migrate with classes that I work on the servers side to also work with them on the Android app - wsdl2java(axis) and the Netbeans Entity Class from table generator - creates a lot of stuff that is not supported in Android

Is there any other Code Genrator that I could use to generate the java classes for Android to consume the REST service with the SpringSource?

And the other problem is that the WCF serializes the DateTime format to sth like: "/Date(1325606580000+0100)/" is there any way to set the RestTemplate so that it will map it correctly to a Java Date?

Thanks in advance for help:)

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` is ambiguous structure and realization is different in any platform, don't use `DateTime` in transport, convetr it to unix timestamp

Comment: Ok, yes, but I generate classes with LINQ and I don't want to modify them so how to modify the WCF serializer so that the DateTime format will be TimeStamp instead of sth like: 2012-01-03T00:00:00 (for XML) - the Java Date parser throws an exception when parsing this...:/

Comment: you can't use datetime without modification, you'll get error anyway